# Boolean law simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I made this exercise but I'm not sure if I made it well.

```
q=(a+b'c)c'+a'b+ac
q=ac'+b'c*c'+a'b+ac
q=ac'+a'b+ac
q=a(c'+c) +a'b
q=a+a'b
q=1
```

Is there someone who can explain if I made it well? I have a little problem to apply boolean rules.

----------------------------------------------- I think that I find the correct solution. 
(x1) +x'y
=xy+xy'+x'y
=xyxy+xy'+x'y
=x(y+y') +y(x+x')
 so in my case it had to be q=a+b

Comment: what does ' mean?

Comment: @BEB00 what exactly?

Comment: You've written q=a+a'b. What does the symbol ' mean? As far as I'm aware, that's not a standard boolean symbol.

Comment: @BeB00 it's a negation. You can use also this kind of symbol like (!) or (-)

Comment: Ignoring all the other parts, it looks like theres a problem with your last step. How does q=a+(!a)b mean that q=1? What if a=0 and b=0?

Comment: @BeB00 because I made so a(1+b)=1 so it will be 1? A'+a=1 and 1+b=1 is it correct?

Comment: What you're saying doesnt make sense. Why does a(1+b)=1? !a+a=1 is correct. 1+b=1 is correct. a+(!a)b=1 is not correct.

Comment: @BeB00 ok I find this rule. (x1) +x'*y=xy+xy'+x'y=xy*xy+xy'+x'y=x(y+y') +y(x+x') so in my case it have to be a+b? Not 1 or 0 how I calculated.. This is correct?

Comment: a+a'b can be simplified, but not to 1.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I think that I already find the solution. If you look at the comment above yours.

Comment: You could have checked your work yourself, with a lot less effort than submitting a question. There are only 8 test cases. If you start off with a=b=c=0 and substitute those values in the first equation you'll find that, for that case, q=0.

Answer (score -1):

With the following two combinations

```
a=0, b=0, c=0
a=0, b=0, c=1
```

q is 0

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but this probably should have been a comment, rather than an answer

Comment: Thanks, I just joined electronics.stackexchange.com and I wanted to add a comment; unfortunately to add comments to the initial post I should have at least 50 reputation - so it is not possible for new joiners. For this reason I decided to show that with some input combinations the output q is not equal to 1.